# django-wysiwyg-redactor / django1.8 / python2.7 can't upload image

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-wysiwyg

I use [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor) with `django 1.8` and `python 2.7.9`. 
Here is my code :

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'redactor',
)

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# WYSIWYG redactor configuration
REDACTOR_OPTIONS = {'lang': 'fr', 'plugins': ['table', 'fontcolor', 'fontsize', 'filemanager', 'imagemanager']}
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = MEDIA_ROOT
REDACTOR_UPLOAD_HANDLER = 'my_app.apps.core.storage.UploadDateDirectoryUploader'
REDACTOR_FILE_STORAGE = 'my_app.apps.core.storage.redactor_storage'
```

All the plugins .js are in the static files.

my_app.apps.core.storage.py:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings

import redactor.handlers
import datetime

redactor_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDI_ROOT, base_url=settings.MEDIA_URL)


class UploadDateDirectoryUploader(redactor.handlers.SimpleUploader):
    """
    Handler  that saves files in a directory based on the current date
    /2014/3/28/filename.etc
    """
    def get_upload_path(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        path = '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(today.year, today.month, today.day)
        return path
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

from redactor.widgets import RedactorEditor

import datetime

LANGUAGES = settings.LANGUAGES

class NewsForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label=_('The news title'), max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(label=_('Enter your message'), widget=RedactorEditor())
    start_date = forms.DateTimeField(label=_('The news will be published the'), initial=datetime.datetime.now())
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField(label=_('The news will be removed the'), required=False)
    active = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    language = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGES, initial='fr', widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

In my template, I have no redactor related code, I generate the form with [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/). Visually, the redactor field is rendered correctly, in the toolbar I have all the plugin button available.
When Redactor is initialized, this redactor view is called :

.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redactor/views.py :

```
import json
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.encoding import force_str

from redactor.forms import ImageForm
from redactor.utils import import_class, is_module_image_installed


class RedactorUploadView(FormView):
    form_class = ImageForm
    http_method_names = ('post',)
    upload_to = getattr(settings, 'REDACTOR_UPLOAD', 'redactor/')
    upload_handler = getattr(settings, 'REDACTOR_UPLOAD_HANDLER',
                             'redactor.handlers.SimpleUploader')

    print "RedactorUploadView : upload_to {0} | upload_handler {1}".format(upload_to, upload_handler)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print "RedactorUploadView dispatch : kwargs : {0}".format(self.kwargs)
        if not is_module_image_installed():
            data = {
                'error': _("ImproperlyConfigured: Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named 'Image'"),
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),
                                content_type='application/json')

        return super(RedactorUploadView, self).dispatch(request, *args,
                                                        **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print "RedactorUploadView form_invalid : kwargs : {0}".format(self.kwargs)
        # TODO: Needs better error messages
        try:
            error = form.errors.values()[-1][-1]
        except:
            error = _('Invalid file.')
        data = {
            'error': error,
        }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print "RedactorUploadView form_valid : kwargs : {0}".format(self.kwargs)
        file_ = form.cleaned_data['file']
        handler_class = import_class(self.upload_handler)
        uploader = handler_class(file_, upload_to=self.kwargs.get('upload_to', None))
        uploader.save_file()
        file_name = force_str(uploader.get_filename())
        file_url = force_str(uploader.get_url())
        data = {
            'filelink': file_url,
            'filename': file_name,
        }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

`upload_to` and `upload_handler` are initialized correctly with `upload_to` being the path to my media folder and `upload_handler` my storage.py `UploadDateDirectoryUploader` class.

But then when I add an image in the wysiwyg, the dispatch class method of redactor view.py is called with `upload_to = ''` !

I've searched for hours for a solution, but I can't understand why suddenly the initial value of upload_to is not my `/media/` folder anymore ?

In my template, I have an alert showing up with `True` inside it (great error message) I think it comes from the default image upload callback function :

redactor/jquery.redactor.init.js :

```
if(typeof django !== "undefined") {
    jQuery = django.jQuery.noConflict(true);
}

var image_upload_error_callback = function (json) {
    // TODO: Needs better error messages
    alert(json.error);
}

redactor_default_options = {
    imageUploadErrorCallback: image_upload_error_callback
};
```

Comment: did you solve it? can you post an anwer if you have it please

Comment: @ArmanceWissal No I did not solve it. But to be fair, I did not work on this project since this issue...

Comment: someone solved it? I have the same issue :(